How to set the tooltip duration of a QListView item
My issue
I have a QListView child class and a QAbstractItemModel child class, say MyModel. I want tooltips for my MyModel items, in MyModel::data, I return a QVariant containing a QString for Qt::ToolTipRole. I do get my tooltip displayed, and I'm happy with their content and style, but they disappear after only 2 or 3 seconds (definitely too brief to read), I want them to stay displayed as long as I don't move the mouse, but a long enough time as five minutes would be great too.
What I've tried

I've tried QWidget::setTooltipDuration() on every related QWidget I could think of.
I've searched for Qt::ItemDataRole::ToolTipPropertyRole on the internet because I found it next to Qt::ItemDataRole::ToolTipRole.

Edit, I also tried @musicamante proposition
I overwritten my delegate's helpEvent:
bool MyDelegate::helpEvent(QHelpEvent *event, QAbstractItemView *view, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index)
{
    if (event->type() == QEvent::ToolTip)
    {
        QVariant toolTipData = view->model()->data(index, Qt::ToolTipRole);
        if (toolTipData.isValid())
        {
            QToolTip::showText(event->globalPos(), toolTipData.toString(), view, QRect(), 1000*60);
            return true;
        }
    }

    return QStyledItemDelegate::helpEvent(event, view, option, index);
}

It is definitly displaying the tooltip just as before, now I set the show time in millisecond from QToolTip::showText last's parameter. But anyway, the tooltip disappear after only 2 or 3 second later, just as it did before. I really don't understand why.
How do I achieve this behavior?

Tooltips in item views are managed by their delegates, specifically by helpEven(). Check the source code and consider creating a custom delegate by implementing it.

That's strange, I recently used that and it works at least on Qt5 on Linux. I've not tested it on Qt6 yet, and a slight change was done in the QToolTip expiration, but that shouldn't affect that; you should also use the correct QRect for the index. Also note that this is considering that no mouse movement happens after the tooltip is shown and the implementation doesn't consider other aspects, so I suggest you to provide more OS/Qt details and a [mre]. (Please always consider to add a reply whenever you update the post in response to a comment, as we cannot follow all posts.)

Instead of using the 'view' as the third parameter for QToolTip::showText, use a newly created QLabel member variable, and provide a valid rectangle as the fourth parameter, such as QRect(0,0,10,10). I tried this on my machine and it achieved the effect you want.

@Ye.Feng That doesn't seem a good idea. Even assuming that memory is properly managed to avoid leaks of "forgotten" labels (yet, how?), it's quite pointless to provide a dummy widget (since what primarily matters is the given rect in widget coordinates), if not even wrong, since mouse movement checks (to eventually hide the tip when leaving the widget) are done in the coordinate system of the given widget, and that widget should also have a proper global position for correct mapping.
